# How to change text that says when you last played the map

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm looking to change the time played and creative text, how can I do this?

[image: Screenshot of minecraft world selection screen]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the date and text by changing the attributes of the world (i.e. changing the default mode of the world, disabling cheats). These are all stored in the world's [level.dat](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Level_format) file, which you can use an [NBT editor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/NBT_format#Software) to modify.

However, you cannot make the text say whatever you want.